# How to match a newly generated name using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, prototype

I am working on an exercism. I am stuck on the first test that asks to match a regex to a new robot's name.

Here is the test ( I am only working on the one that doesn't have the x in front of it ).

var Robot = require('./robot-name');

```
describe("Robot", function() {
  it("has a name", function() {
    var robot = new Robot();
    expect(robot.name).toMatch(/\w{2}\d{3}/);
  });

  xit("name is the same each time", function() {
    var robot = new Robot();
    expect(robot.name).toEqual(robot.name);
  });

  xit("different robots have different names", function() {
    var robotOne = new Robot();
    var robotTwo = new Robot();
    expect(robotOne.name).not.toEqual(robotTwo.name);
  });

  xit("is able to reset the name", function() {
    var robot = new Robot();
    var originalName = robot.name;
    robot.reset();
    var newName = robot.name;
    expect(originalName).not.toEqual(newName);
  });
});
```

Here is my guess that isn't working.

```
var Robot = function(){

  this.name = {};

  Robot.prototype.new = function(robotNumber){
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 5;
    var newName = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5);

    newName = MyRe.exec("/\w{2}\d{3}/");

    newName.push(robotNumber);
    this.name(newName);
  };


};
module.exports = Robot;
```

Error message is on line 6 and responds:
Expected {  } to match /\w{2}\d{3}/.

If anyone can point me in a direction of great resources for using prototypes and regex in javascript, it would be really helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Good luck for your exorcism.

Answer (score 0):

`MyRe` should be your regex such as `/\w{2}\d{3}/g` and `.exec()` should take in your string. You haven't defined `MyRe`. You could just write something like `/\w{2}\d{3}/.exec(newName)` if you wanted to be concise.

After trying to read your code it makes absolutely no sense. I can't even begin to imagine what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

In Your regex `/\w{2}\d{3}/`

`\w{2}` indicates *word characters* `(a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)` *(2 times)* and

`\d{3}` indicates *digits* `(0-9)` *(3 times)*

And `\w{2}\d{3}` can be represented as,

[image]

And a matching example is : `ab123`